# Embed cells in Site + SAGE

Tags: sage

I like use the SAGE to embed any code (example below). But I want linked two cells using this instruction but this not work. How I will be able to fix this?. 
For example I trying call from "compute" cell the function Hola() in the cell "mycell".

```
<script>
$(function () {
// Make the div with id 'mycell' a Sage cell
sagecell.makeSagecell({inputLocation: '#mycell',

                       evalButtonText: 'Evaluate'});
// Make *any* div with class 'compute' a Sage cell
sagecell.makeSagecell({inputLocation: 'div.compute',
                       linked: true,
                       evalButtonText: 'Evaluate'});
});
</script>
<div id="mycell">
<script type="text/x-sage">
def Hola():
    print "Hola"
</script>
</div> 
<div class="compute"><script type="text/x-sage">
Hola()
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have two different types.  The `linked:true` will only work inside of each `makeSagecell` call div type, if I'm not mistaken.  I haven't tried anything else, but it seems reasonable that your example would not work - and `linked:true` definitely *does* work with all within the same class, or my lecture notes for today wouldn't work!

Edit:  Here's what I do, or at least an example.  This seems to work fine.

```
$(function () {
    // Make *any* div with class 'compute' a Sage cell
    sagecell.makeSagecell({inputLocation: 'div.compute',
                           evalButtonText: 'Evaluate',
                           linked:true});
});

[snip]
<div class="compute"><script type="text/x-sage">
def r2(n):
    n = prime_to_m_part(n,2)
    F = factor(n)
    ret = 4
    for a,b in F:
        if a%4==3:
            if b%2==1:
                return 0
            else:
                n = prime_to_m_part(n,a)
        else:
            ret = ret * (b+1)
    return ret

def L(n):
    ls = []
    out = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        out += r2(i)
        ls.append((i,out/i))
    return ls
</script></div>

<div class="compute"><script type="text/x-sage">
@interact
def _(n=100):
    P = line(L(n))
    P += plot(pi+pi*sqrt(2)/sqrt(x),x,3,n,color='red')
    P += plot(pi-pi*sqrt(2)/sqrt(x),x,3,n,color='red')
    P += plot(pi,x,3,n,color='red',linestyle='--')
    show(P)
</script></div>
```

I would also ask on ask.sagemath.org if you continue to have trouble.

Comment: Thanks by your reply but this yet not work.

    $(function () {
       // Make the div with id 'mycell' a Sage cell
       sagecell.makeSagecell({inputLocation: 'div.compute',
                           linked: true,
                           evalButtonText: 'Evaluate'});
     });
     </script>

    <div class="compute">
    <script type="text/x-sage">
    def Hola():
        print "Hola" 
    </script>
</div>

<div class="compute">
<script type="text/x-sage">
Hola()
</script>
</div>